# WordPress: wp_nav_menu sometimes is messed up

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I use the wordpress funcion `wp_nav_menu()` to display a hierarchical menu I created in my WP menu. Here's the snippet:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu('show_home=1&menu_class=page-navi&sort_column=menu_order'); ?>
```

Here's its html output:

```
<div class="menu-default-container"><ul class="page-navi" id="menu-default"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-127" id="menu-item-127"><a href="http://domain.tld/">Home Page</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-128" id="menu-item-128"><a href="http://domain.tld/?page_id=7">Il film</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-129" id="menu-item-129"><a href="http://domain.tld/?page_id=9">Di che cosa parla?</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-133" id="menu-item-133"><a href="http://domain.tld/?page_id=121">Una storia di occasioni</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-130" id="menu-item-130"><a href="http://domain.tld/?page_id=11">Il Regista</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-131" id="menu-item-131"><a href="http://domain.tld/?page_id=14">Il “maestro”</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-139" id="menu-item-139"><a href="http://domain.tld/?page_id=34">Incontri e discussioni</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-153" id="menu-item-153"><a href="http://domain.tld/?page_id=144">News ed eventi</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-141" id="menu-item-141"><a href="http://domain.tld/?page_id=36">Film e lavoro in classe</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-142" id="menu-item-142"><a href="http://domain.tld/?page_id=62">Il titolo del film</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-134" id="menu-item-134"><a href="http://domain.tld/?page_id=23">Interviste</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-19 current_page_item menu-item-138" id="menu-item-138"><a href="http://domain.tld/?page_id=19">Sponsor e collaborazioni</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-151" id="menu-item-151"><a href="http://domain.tld/?page_id=148">Contatti</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-158" id="menu-item-158"><a href="http://domain.tld/?page_id=156">Credits</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

The problem is that sometimes it's displayed properly:

[image]

.. and others isn't:
[image]

I checked the source code and it's THE SAME!! :o

Don't know what to think. These things scare me! :P
Here's the website if you want to try to reproduce this (if you're lucky.. in the nights of full moon)..

Comment: If the markup in the source is exactly the same then the visual differences must be due to CSS.

Comment: They're both pages, same (not custom) template.. I really don't know :o

Comment: This is the page where I'm seeing it messed up right now: http://waiting4maestro.org/?page_id=19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because of this style:

```
ul li {
display: inline;
padding: 2px;
}
```

Adding the following style to your css should fix your problem:

```
.menu-default-container ul li {
display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: I'm gonna try now but... why the different rending if CSS is the same? :o

Comment: Because if you look in the source of the page you will see that it was added specially for that page. You might need to add `!important` after block.